# Isn't Android Studio 2.2 missing some features?

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 2.2 is a disappointment for me, it's harder to work on.
The changes to the properties are so drastic, I can't do some things I used to do.
For example I am missing the align: top:top, left:right.. and the others..
How am I supposed to center an object inside another object?

Comment: The only thing added is the `ConstraintLayout` and the properties for it. Mainly the rest of the things are not changed.

Comment: There are a lot of changes to the UI.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The UI elements of IDE are just rearranged. I think you **will need** that properties if you are **not** using newly introduced `ConstraintLayout`. In that case, the properties are here:

[image]

Comment: Yep, I started using ConstraintLayout, it's way better.

Comment: Consider accepting and upvoting my answer if it helped you